# VHDL Two Type Declarations In A Package Create An Error

Tags: vhdl, hdl, vivado

I am trying to build up a self made package for a VHDL project using Vivado and am having an error when I add more than one type declaration.

```
package TypeDef is
type IntCommand is (meW, meA, meO, meB);

--    type TestType is array (0 to 3) of STD_LOGIC;

type Rec is record
    inst : IntCommand;
    num1 : STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(3 downto 0);
    num2 : STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(3 downto 0);
end record Rec;

end package TypeDef;
```

If I comment out the line that is commented out with the 'TestType' the package is able to work all the way through to simulation. However, if I uncomment that line of code or add in any other variation of type the design has an error when attempting to simulate. The error on the elaborate step.

Cheers,

Comment: Note you do not provide a context clause for this design unit. Adding that we find several semantic errors. A redeclaration of meA in type IntCommand and an attempt to use inst as both an element of  a record and a type mark. There is no visible type declaration for Inst. Show your error messages and a [mcve].

Comment: I changed the variable names when I uploaded the question. I didn't notice the errors I made. Thanks.

Comment: EEE Std 1076-2008 14.2 Elaboration of a design hierarchy The elaboration of a design hierarchy creates a collection of processes interconnected by nets; this collection of processes and nets can then be executed to simulate the behavior of the design. A package doesn't contain any process statements or concurrent statements with equivalents, see 11. Concurrent statements and 3. Design entities and configurations. Provide a [mcve] and your actual error messages.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After searching around for the error I found it to be rather simple to fix. I only needed to edit and then save the main file. The error message found in 'elaborlate.log' was 'core.vdb needs to be re-saved since xil_defaultlib.typedef changed'.